# Two homomorphisms must be equal if $ \phi (a) = \psi (a) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given $G_1$, a cyclic group, and $G_2$ a group with $\phi$ and $\psi$ homomorphisms from $G_1$ to $G_2$ how can I show that $\phi=\psi$ if and only if $\phi(a)=\psi(a)$

Comment: I think the question is missing the rather important data that $\;G_1=\langle a\rangle\;$ , otherwise either it makes no sense or else it is false.

Comment: you're right that should have been in the question

Answer (score 2):

The "if" direction is trivial. For the "only if", consider the since $\phi(a) = \psi(a)$, we have that $\phi(a)^n = \psi(a)^n$. Hence $\phi(a^n) = \psi(a^n)$, for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Why does this prove the other direction?

Comment: Does this prove the other direction because $G_1$ is cyclic so $a^n \in G_1$ for all n?

Comment: @Vivid Well, every group is closed under multiplication, so $a^n \in G \iff a \in G$ is always true. However, since your group is cyclic, the $a^n$ are the only elements in $G$, so the equality holds for all elements in $G$.

Comment: Right thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is a generator of $G_1$ then all elements in $G_1$ can be written as $a^n$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Now it should follow from the definition of the homomorphism that they are equal everywhere. The converse is obvious.

If $a$ is not a generator then this isn't necessarly true.